# Postman: wp_mail has been declared by another plugin or theme

Tags: wp-mail, pluggable

I need use Postman for sending email using an SMTP server, but when installed, it shows this message:

> Postman: wp_mail has been declared by another plugin or theme, so you
>   won't be able to use Postman until the conflict is resolved.

I've uninstalled all unnecessary plugins; but it still does not work.

Searching all files for `wp_mail()` and the other plugins that use `wp_mail()` are:

```
./wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/freemius/includes/class-freemius.php
./wp-content/plugins/planso-forms/includes/submit_notifications.php
```

I need these plugins and I don't understand how to resolve this issue.

I read something about bad use for any plugins, of pluggable.php, but I don't search anything for NextGen gallery.

Planso forms, it's already prepared for use Postman, and not problem with plugabble.

Answer (score 1):

(I know this is a late answer, so this user has probably moved on; but I'm answering this in the hopes that if a future user ends up here seeking a similar solution, that the following will help them find it.)

The problem that Postman is telling you about is that the function `wp_mail()` has already been declared as a function, so it cannot be redeclared.

What you need to locate is a plugin that has declared `wp_mail()` as a function.  The two example files you gave do not declare it as a function. Those files are *using* the function, which is fine.

What you need to find is a file that declares `function wp_mail() {...`

The first test you need to do in this kind of situation is deactivate all plugins. If the problem goes away, then reactivate plugins one-by-one and retest until you locate the conflicting plugin.  Once you've narrowed down the offending combination, then you can develop a course of action.

If the only reason you're using Postman in this case is to send email via SMTP, then it may be easier to seek another possible solution.  [You can do it without a plugin, and without redeclaring `wp_mail()`](https://www.butlerblog.com/2013/12/12/easy-smtp-email-wordpress-wp_mail/).  There are also other plugin solutions that you could try.